# how to get data seesion id and all from external url given, which not from my app(routing) in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular6, angular2-routing

Url: https://admin/workadd/cust_session?sessionId=1500c980954d7a81e6c428a16d8c25&srId=SR1234&custId=cust12345&custName=sam

This url is external given by backend to me, i need to fetch the data from url like session id, srid and all,
Whenever user clicks on this link it should open in my app and fetch details from url, my app in angular 6 using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

  export class AppComponent{
    public session;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{
        this.session = params['sessionId'];
        console.log("SessionId ",this.session)
       });
      }
    }
```